# Unencrypted Communications are disallowed

Tags: autonomy, interwoven, imanage, hp-haven

I am trying to leverage the IDOL Web API (if that is its name) so that I can programmatically validate document creation/modification actions triggering an IDOL crawl of said document. We had a situation where a few documents were seemingly crawled by IDOL, but never made it to one of the 13 content engines. What I want to do is execute a script hourly to quickly validate that all documents created/modified in the preceding hour are in the IDOL index. This should be "easy" based upon some of the examples I have found.

Executing this http://[server]:9000/ACTION=licenseInfo and I get this response in the browser:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <autnresponse xmlns:autn="http://schemas.autonomy.com/aci/"> 
<action>LICENSEINFO</action> 
<response>ERROR</response> 
- <responsedata> 
- <error> 
<errorid>IDOLPROXYLICENSEINFO-2147441838</errorid> 
<rawerrorid>0x8000A352</rawerrorid> 
<errorstring>Unencrypted communications are disallowed</errorstring> 
<errorcode>ERRORENCRYPTIONFAILED</errorcode> 
<errortime>08 Aug 12 10:23:02</errortime> 
</error> 
</responsedata> 
</autnresponse>
```

Executing this http://[server]:9000/ACTION=query&text=toys and I get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <autnresponse xmlns:autn="http://schemas.autonomy.com/aci/"> 
<action>QUERY</action> 
<response>ERROR</response> 
- <responsedata> 
- <error> 
<errorid>IDOLPROXYQUERY-2147441838</errorid> 
<rawerrorid>0x8000A352</rawerrorid> 
<errorstring>Unencrypted communications are disallowed</errorstring> 
<errorcode>ERRORENCRYPTIONFAILED</errorcode> 
<errortime>08 Aug 12 10:26:40</errortime> 
</error> 
</responsedata> 
</autnresponse>
```

Is there something I am missing in my IIS setup?

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question in another [forum](http://knowledgemanagement.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/autonomy-l/unencrypted-communications-are-disallowed-4885126) that seems to be more active for users of the Autonomy/Interwoven suite of products.  Basically, the version of the IDOL indexer that comes built-in with the WorkSite Indexer does not allow Web API calls.